# Android studio : My project don't understand support package from Action Bar Sherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

Like the title, I am facing the problem when import my project from Eclipse to Android studio.
The flow is :
- Import my project
- Download the latest Action Bar Sherlock and import it like a module.

Then I make the project but I got the error that the support package it missing. 
I tried to add the support package to my project in Modules Setting but after that it show some error like duplicate lib. (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoStubImpl...)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The post below has some really great answers.

[How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio/16630511#16630511)

Also, sounds like you need to set the module in question to "Provided" vs. "Compile".  This will tell your project that it can safely use the library/jar, but it doesn't need to recompile it b/c it's already being compiled by a different module.